# Meteor update crashes - "MINISAT-out: Cannot enlarge memory arrays."

Tags: meteor

I got this notification: `Newer versions of the following indirect dependencies are available:
 * aldeed:tabular 1.6.1 (2.0.2 is available)`

So, I ran `meteor update --all-packages` and it didn't update.

So I added `aldeed:tabular@2.0.2` to the packages file.

I am getting this error while running `meteor update --all-packages` with that added to the packages file.

```
This project is already at Meteor 1.4.2, the latest release.
MINISAT-out: Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X with X higher than the current value 67108864, (2) compile with ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH which adjusts the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, or (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY before the program runs.
MINISAT-err: Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X with X higher than the current value 67108864, (2) compile with ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH which adjusts the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, or (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY before the program runs.

/Users/nathancain/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2.zi1w5b++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/ddp/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^
abort() at Error
    at jsStackTrace (packages/logic-solver.js:22:18626)
    at stackTrace (packages/logic-solver.js:22:18809)
    at abort (packages/logic-solver.js:52:28956)
    at enlargeMemory (packages/logic-solver.js:22:19142)
    at Function.Runtime.dynamicAlloc [as alloc] (packages/logic-solver.js:22:7927)
    at _sbrk (packages/logic-solver.js:22:58803)
    at Sd (packages/logic-solver.js:26:98389)
    at Ud (packages/logic-solver.js:26:109800)
    at mc (packages/logic-solver.js:26:44840)
    at Ob (packages/logic-solver.js:26:14353)
    at Pb (packages/logic-solver.js:26:15704)
    at Xb (packages/logic-solver.js:26:26622)
    at Zb (packages/logic-solver.js:26:27957)
    at _b (packages/logic-solver.js:26:30575)
    at $b (packages/logic-solver.js:26:35130)
    at Bc (packages/logic-solver.js:26:54870)
    at Object.hd [as _solveAssuming] (packages/logic-solver.js:26:84479)
    at [object Object].MiniSat.solveAssuming (packages/logic-solver.js:157:18)
    at [object Object].Logic.Solver.solve (packages/logic-solver.js:1681:33)
    at [object Object].Logic.Solver.solveAssuming (packages/logic-solver.js:1714:21)
    at minMaxWS (packages/logic-solver.js:2022:32)
    at [object Object].Logic.Solver.minimizeWeightedSum (packages/logic-solver.js:2087:10)
    at packages/constraint-solver.js:1326:28
    at Function.time (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:305:10)
    at [object Object].CS.Solver.minimize (packages/constraint-solver.js:1310:16)
    at packages/constraint-solver.js:1286:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:139:11)
    at [object Object].CS.Solver.minimize (packages/constraint-solver.js:1285:7)
    at [object Object].CS.Solver._getAnswer (packages/constraint-solver.js:1733:8)
    at packages/constraint-solver.js:1561:17
    at Function.time (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:305:10)
    at [object Object].CS.Solver.getAnswer (packages/constraint-solver.js:1560:23)
    at packages/constraint-solver.js:2258:25
    at Object.Logic.disablingAssertions (packages/logic-solver.js:390:12)
    at Function.CS.PackagesResolver._resolveWithInput (packages/constraint-solver.js:2257:16)
    at [object Object].CS.PackagesResolver.resolve (packages/constraint-solver.js:2221:34)
    at /tools/project-context.js:518:35
    at Function.time (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:305:10)
    at /tools/project-context.js:514:19
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:359:18
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:352:34
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:350:23
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at /tools/project-context.js:486:20
    at /tools/packaging/catalog/catalog.js:100:5
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:271:13
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:264:29
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:262:18
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:253:23
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at Object.catalog.runAndRetryWithRefreshIfHelpful (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog.js:99:31)
    at ProjectContext._resolveConstraints (/tools/project-context.js:485:13)
    at /tools/project-context.js:268:9
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:359:18
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:352:34
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:350:23
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at ProjectContext._completeStagesThrough (/tools/project-context.js:258:18)
    at /tools/project-context.js:228:12
    at Function.run (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:490:12)
    at ProjectContext.resolveConstraints (/tools/project-context.js:227:13)
    at /tools/cli/commands-packages.js:1682:22
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:271:13
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:264:29
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:262:18
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:253:23
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at Object.main.captureAndExit (/tools/cli/main.js:271:29)
    at Command.func (/tools/cli/commands-packages.js:1680:8)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:1454:23
If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can give more information.
```

(Stackoverflow is saying I need to add more details, but I don't have any right now.)

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove yogiben:admin because of its dependency on an older version of aldeed:tabular.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add yogiben:admin back again and it should work.